# What is the meaning of "ps -aef | grep $(pwd)" command?

Tags: command-line, grep, ps

What is the meaning of this command, what does it do?

```bsh
ps -aef | grep `pwd`
```

Comment: it is probably used to find out processes whose binaries/scripts are located in (or underneath) the current directory. If you start a process with /path/to/the/file , and you go in /path/to, the `ps -aef | grep $(pwd)` will do a `ps -aef | grep /path/to` and should show that process as its full path is /path/to/the/file

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the man page for [ps](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ps.1.html):

```
   -a              Select all processes except both session leaders (see getsid(2)) and
                   processes not associated with a terminal.

   -f              Do full-format listing. This option can be combined
                   with many other UNIX-style options to add additional
                   columns. It also causes the command arguments to be
                   printed. When used with -L, the NLWP (number of
                   threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be added. See
                   the c option, the format keyword args, and the format
                   keyword comm.
   -e              Select all processes. Identical to -A.
```

[grep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/grep.1.html) is used to `print lines matching a pattern`.

**What it does**

The command

```
ps -aef | grep `pwd`
```

prints out all the lines matching the output of the command `pwd`(which will be the path your current working directory), from the output of `ps -aef`.

**e.g:**

```
saji@geeklap:~$ pwd
/home/saji

saji@geeklap:~$ ps -aef | grep `pwd`
saji      2854  2814  0 09:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/gpg-agent --daemon --sh --write-env-file=/home/saji/.gnupg/gpg-agent-info-geeklap /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
saji      2855  2814  0 09:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --daemon --sh --write-env-file=/home/saji/.gnupg/gpg-agent-info-geeklap /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session gnome-session --session=ubuntu
saji      2879     1  0 09:51 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/gvfs//gvfs-fuse-daemon -f /home/saji/.gvfs
saji     14242 14148  0 15:26 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto /home/saji
```

As you can see the output shows the lines matching my current working directory, which is `/home/saji`.

**Background info:**
If a command is in $(...) or `...`, then the command is run and the output (what is printed to the screen) is caught and substituted to where the original $() or `` string was. So the actual command run is grep pwd.

For more information refer this [link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).(Thanks to [@minerz029](https://askubuntu.com/users/176889/minerz029) for this information).

Do check out the following link for a detailed technical answer from the man pages itself:

http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=ps+-aef+|+grep+%60pwd%60

Comment: Actually, it does not make sense to use the attribute you have mentioned isn BSD style and with "-" option all the options acts as UNIX option.

So the attribute we should be looking at is "-a" 
which means as below 
    `-a     Select all processes except both session leaders (see getsid(2)) and processes not associated with a
              terminal.`

Comment: @Ajay Thanks for pointing out, I have updated the relevant section.

Answer (score 3):

```
ps -aef | grep $(pwd)
```

Searching,Getting and displaying full information about the list of processes which are associated with the `working directory` and print the path of that directory.

Answer (score 2):

`ps`: Displays information about a selection of the active processes.
like `ps -e` for displaying all current working background processes

I cant understand what is **-aef** here

`grep`: Is for searching that specific work within process.

`pwd`: Print working directory .

I don't think its an useful and meaningful command. May I know for what purpose you are using it.